# I want to save plots generated from the loop using the given code. I am unable to save the plots in one file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to save the plots generated in the code in one jpg, with common  column y axis and x axis.

```
    d<-read.csv("HDI_Div_yearly_data.csv", T, sep = ",")
mydf<-as.data.frame(d)
plotlist<-list()
myaxis <- colnames(mydf[1])
mynames <- colnames(mydf[-1])
myaxis
mynames
library(ggplot2)
p<-for (i in seq_along(mynames)) {
  print(ggplot(mydf, aes_string(x = myaxis, y = mynames[[i]], group = 1)) + geom_line(color="red", size=1) + geom_point(color="red", size=0.1 )+
          theme_minimal()+
          theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major =element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
          scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.1)))+
          labs(x= "Year", y= "No of cases recorded")+
          ggtitle(paste0(mynames[[i]]))
            )
    }
```

I have tried facet_wrap but it did not extract any results.

Comment: If you want one plot, why loop at all? Sounds like you want facets.

Comment: Would be better with an minimal example, but your syntax of the loop is wrong. you assign an object within the loop, hence before the `print()` function, not in front of the loop.